# Fire an AngularJS UI-Modal from two different elements without ng-click or .click() on one of the elements

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap

I would like to call the Confirm Dialog from the Confirm Dialog button as well as the Next button. I do **not** want to add a ng-click event to the next button or use javascript to fire a .click() event. How can I load open the modal using the next button without any click events on the element or in the javascript code?

### http://codepen.io/fauverism/pen/pEbJk

Comment: So its not that you don't want an event listener attached to the Next button, you just specifically don't want a click event attached?

Comment: How do you expect to trigger this "call confirm dialog" event?

Comment: I'd love to load the modal via a function

Comment: on What action do you want to load the modal or do you want default by page load?

Comment: Click the *Next* button but do not call the modal with the same click that is loading the modal via the *Confirm Dialog* button